# Indexing multiple columns and using the .fillna command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I input this code:

candy.loc[:, "Q6 | 100 Grand Bar":"Q11: DAY"].fillna('NO_ANSWER')

I am trying to fill in those selected columns to fill in the NaN values with NO_ANSWER. I use this code for my Candy dataframe and the NaN answers are not changing. Trying to see what I did wrong here, I haven't had to index several columns before and use the fillna function for Pandas yet.

I also created a slice of the data:

candy_slice = candy.loc[:, "Q6 | 100 Grand Bar":"Q11: DAY"]

so I was also trying to use this slice as well to update my candy dataframe but nothing seems to work

I have tried numerous other codes for indexing but I am clearly missing something

Comment: You have to assign the output: `candy.loc[:, "Q6 | 100 Grand Bar":"Q11: DAY"] = candy.loc[:, "Q6 | 100 Grand Bar":"Q11: DAY"].fillna('NO_ANSWER')`